# Adding another array to store the names of store as array of strings

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, store

What I need to do:

Add another array to store the names of the stores. It should be an array of strings. Add the `stores[]` array to the parameters of each method.

I'm reading this inputfile `input.csv` that has this values:

```
Name     Number    Store
natto      3        Don Quijote
eggs       12       Whole Foods
shiitake    1      farmer's market
negi       1        farmer's market
garlic     5           Costco
umeboshi    1        Don Quijote
```

And the end it should be written to the output file `output.csv`

So my code should shows up like this with the store displayed and included:

```
Read from file: input4.csv

    GROCERY LIST MENU
     Enter 1 to Add
     Enter 2 to Delete
     Enter 3 to Display
     Enter 4 to Quit
    Enter your choice: 3

Row        Name    Number    Store
 1        natto       3    Don Quijote
 2         eggs      12    Whole Foods
 3     shiitake       1    farmer's market
 4         negi       1    farmer's market
 5       garlic       5    Costco
 6     umeboshi       1    Don Quijote

    GROCERY LIST MENU
     Enter 1 to Add
     Enter 2 to Delete
     Enter 3 to Display
     Enter 4 to Quit
    Enter your choice: 1

Enter name of item: BANANAS
Enter number of items: 100
Enter store of item: COSTCO
Added row #7: BANANAS 100 COSTCO

    GROCERY LIST MENU
     Enter 1 to Add
     Enter 2 to Delete
     Enter 3 to Display
     Enter 4 to Quit
    Enter your choice: 3

Row        Name    Number    Store
 1        natto       3    Don Quijote
 2         eggs      12    Whole Foods
 3     shiitake       1    farmer's market
 4         negi       1    farmer's market
 5       garlic       5    Costco
 6     umeboshi       1    Don Quijote
 7      BANANAS     100    COSTCO

    GROCERY LIST MENU
     Enter 1 to Add
     Enter 2 to Delete
     Enter 3 to Display
     Enter 4 to Quit
    Enter your choice: 2

Enter the row number of the item you wish to delete: 3
Deleting row #3: shiitake 1 farmer's market

    GROCERY LIST MENU
     Enter 1 to Add
     Enter 2 to Delete
     Enter 3 to Display
     Enter 4 to Quit
    Enter your choice: 3

Row        Name    Number    Store
 1        natto       3    Don Quijote
 2         eggs      12    Whole Foods
 3         negi       1    farmer's market
 4       garlic       5    Costco
 5     umeboshi       1    Don Quijote
 6      BANANAS     100    COSTCO

    GROCERY LIST MENU
     Enter 1 to Add
     Enter 2 to Delete
     Enter 3 to Display
     Enter 4 to Quit
    Enter your choice: 4

Wrote to file: output4.csv
```

My code right now only shows the ability to add, delete, display the row, name and number except the store list. Is there a way for me to follow this format above so it can:

1. When I press 3, it would show the store list
2. When I press 1 I can also Enter store of item: after entering the name and number of the item
3. When I press 4 I can also delete the item listed including its store

**edit:** I fixed everything on my code but I can't seem to display, add, or delete the store names to the array is it not reading from the file?
my new updated code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.lang.Integer;


public class TestRun1 {


/** Stores the first line of the file, which has the headings  */
   public static String firstLineOfFile = ""; 

   /**
    * The main() Method Starts The Program.
    * 
    * @param commandlineArguments 1st argument is INPUT File, 2nd argument is OUTPUT File
    */
   public static void main(String[] commandlineArguments) {
      // Error Checking For 2 Command Line Arguments..
      if (commandlineArguments.length != 2) {
         System.out.println("Please enter the INPUT file name as the 1st commandline argument.");
         System.out.println("Please enter the OUTPUT file name as the 2nd commandline argument.");
         System.out.println("Please enter exactly two (2) commandline arguments.");
      // Immediately terminates program
         System.exit(1);   
      }// end of if
   // if no commandline argument errors, continue program

   // Declare and instantiate array of 100 Strings and Integers
      final Integer MAX_SIZE = new Integer(100);
      String itemNames[] = new String[MAX_SIZE];
      Integer itemNumbers[] = new Integer[MAX_SIZE];
      String StoreNames[] = new String[MAX_SIZE];
   // Set size of grocery list to zero (0) items
      Integer size = new Integer(0);
   // read grocery items from file & store in arrays for grocery list
      try {
         size = TestRun1.readFromFile(commandlineArguments[0],
                 itemNames, itemNumbers, size, StoreNames);
      } 
      catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException exception) {
         System.out.print("ERROR: Too many items in input file. ");
         System.out.println("Please limit to " + MAX_SIZE + " items.");
      // Immediately terminates program
         System.exit(1);
      }

   // user's choice for Menu
      Integer choice = new Integer(0);
   // choice for ending program
      final Integer QUIT = new Integer(4);
   // if the user does NOT want to QUIT, keep looping
      while (false == choice.equals(QUIT)) {
      // get the user's choice
         choice = TestRun1.displayMenu();
      // add grocery item
         if (choice.equals(1)) {
            size = TestRun1.add(itemNames, itemNumbers, size, StoreNames);
         }
         // delete grocery item
         else if (choice.equals(2)) {
            size = TestRun1.delete(itemNames, itemNumbers, size, StoreNames);
         }
             // display grocery item
         else if (choice.equals(3)) {
            TestRun1.display(itemNames, itemNumbers, size, StoreNames);
         }
             // error message
         else if (false == choice.equals(QUIT)) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: Please enter an integer in the range from 1 to 4");
         }
      }// end of "while"

      // write to from grocery list array to OUTPUT file
      TestRun1.writeToFile(commandlineArguments[1], 
         itemNames, itemNumbers, size, StoreNames);
   }// end of main() method

   /**
    * Displays the menu for the program and returns user's choice
    * 
    * @return the choice of the user (if error, returns 0)
    */
   public static Integer displayMenu() {
      // display menu
      System.out.println();
      System.out.println("\tGROCERY LIST MENU");
      System.out.println("\t Enter 1 to Add");
      System.out.println("\t Enter 2 to Delete");
      System.out.println("\t Enter 3 to Display");
      System.out.println("\t Enter 4 to Quit");
      System.out.print("\tEnter your choice: ");
      // get input from user
      Scanner keyboardInput = new Scanner(System.in);
      String userInput = new String("");
      Integer choiceOfUser = new Integer(0);
      //get next word from user (hopefully, it is a number)
      userInput = keyboardInput.next();
      try {
         // non-integer input will throw an exception
         choiceOfUser = Integer.parseInt(userInput);
      } 
      catch (NumberFormatException exception) {
         System.out.println("ERROR: " + userInput + " is not a number!");
      }
      System.out.println();
      return choiceOfUser;
   }

   /**
    * Reads grocery items from a file and stores items in an array
    * 
    * @param inputFile is the INPUT File
    * @param itemNames2 is the array of item names in the grocery list
    * @param itemNumbers2 is the array of item numbers in the grocery list    
    * @param size is the number of items in Grocery List
    * @return the new size of the grocery list
    * @throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException if array size is less than number of
    *         items in input file
    */
   public static Integer readFromFile(String inputFile, String[] itemNames2,
       Integer itemNumbers2[], Integer size, String[] StoreNames2) throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException {
      // connect to file (does NOT create new file)
      File file = new File(inputFile);
      Scanner scanFile = null;
      try {
         scanFile = new Scanner(file);
      } 
      catch (FileNotFoundException exception) {
         // Print error message.
         // In order to print double quotes("),
         // the escape sequence for double quotes (\") must be used.
         System.out.print("ERROR: File not found for \"");
         System.out.println(inputFile + "\"");
      }
      // if made connection to file, read from file
      if (scanFile != null) {
      //first line of file is the headers, so don't store in the arrays
         firstLineOfFile = scanFile.nextLine();

         // keeps looping if file has more lines..
         while (scanFile.hasNextLine()) {
            // get a line of text..
            String line = scanFile.nextLine();

         // divides each line by commas
            Scanner lineInput = new Scanner(line).useDelimiter(",");
         //get the name and count from one line in the file   
            String name = lineInput.next();
            String count1 = lineInput.next();
            String store = lineInput.next();

         //convert the string count to integer count2  
            Integer count2 = 0; 
            try{
               count2 = Integer.parseInt(count1);
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException exception) {
               System.out.println("ERROR: " + count1 + " is not a number!");
               //if it is not an integer, then use zero (0) as default
            }
            //check for negative numbers
            if(count2 < 0){
            //change to positive integer
               count2 = -count2;
            }

            //assign and count2 to appropriate arrays
            itemNames2[size] = name;
            itemNumbers2[size] = count2;
            StoreNames2 [size] = store;
            // increment size
            ++size;
         }
         // In order to print double quotes("),
         // the escape sequence for double quotes (\") must be used.
         System.out.println("Read from file: " + inputFile);
      }// end of "if" for connecting to file
      return size;
   }

   /**
    * Adds a grocery item to an array
    * 
    * @param itemNames3 is the array of item names in the grocery list
    * @param itemNumbers3 is the array of item numbers in the grocery list    
    * @param listSize is the size of the grocery list
    * @return new size of the grocery list
    */
   public static Integer add(String[] itemNames3, 
   Integer[] itemNumbers3, Integer size, String[] StoreNames3){
      // get item from user
      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("Enter name of item: ");
      String name = keyboard.nextLine();
      System.out.print("Enter number of items: ");
      String count1 = keyboard.nextLine();   
      System.out.print("Enter name of store ");
      String store = keyboard.nextLine();

   //convert the string count to integer count2  
      Integer count2 = 0; 
      try{
         count2 = Integer.parseInt(count1);
      }
      catch (NumberFormatException exception) {
         System.out.println("ERROR: " + count2 + " is not a number!");
      //if it is not an integer, then use zero (0) as default
      }
   //check for negative numbers
      if(count2 < 0){
      //change to positive integer
         count2 = -count2;
      }

   //assign name and count2 to appropriate arrays at end 
      itemNames3[size] = name;
      itemNumbers3[size] = count2;
      StoreNames3[size] = store;
   //give feedback to user to let them know what is being addded
      System.out.println("Added row #" + (size + 1) + ": " 
            + itemNames3[size] + " " + itemNumbers3[size] + " " + StoreNames3[size]); 

      // add one to the size (one item to end of list)
      return size + 1;
   }

   /**
    * Deletes a grocery item from parallet arrays
    * 
    * @param itemNames4 is the item names in the grocery list
    * @param itemNumbers4 is the number of items in the grocery list
    * @param listSize is the size of the grocery list
    * @return new size of the grocery list
    */
   public static Integer delete(String[] itemNames4, 
   Integer[] itemNumbers4, Integer listSize, String[] StoreNames4) {
      // get user input
      System.out.print("Enter the row number of the item you wish to delete: ");
      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
      try {
         // throws an exception if not an integer
         Integer row = keyboard.nextInt();
         // check for negative integers
         if (row <= 0) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: The row number cannot be negative or zero.");
         }
          // check for row number too big
         else if (row > listSize + 1) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: The row number is too big for the list.");
         } 
         else {
         //convert row to an index in the array by subtracting one
            Integer index = row - 1;
            //give feedback to user to let them know what is being deleted
            System.out.println("Deleting row #" + row + ": " 
               + itemNames4[index] + " " + itemNumbers4[index]+ " " + StoreNames4[index]); 

            // delete item by shifting items on the right of the item to the left
            for (int i = index; i < listSize; i++) {
               itemNames4[i] = itemNames4[i + 1];
               itemNumbers4[i] = itemNumbers4[i + 1];
               StoreNames4[i] = StoreNames4[i + 1];
            }
            // subtract one from the size (one item deleted from list)
            --listSize;
         }
      } 
      catch (InputMismatchException exception) {
         System.out.println("ERROR: You must enter an integer to delete an item.");
      }
      return listSize;
   }

   /**
    * Displays a the grocery list
    * 
    * @param itemNames5 is the grocery list's item names
    * @param itemNumbers5 is the grocery list's item numbers
    * @param listSize is the size of the grocery list
    */
   public static void display(String[] itemNames5, 
   Integer[] itemNumbers5, Integer listSize, String [] StoreNames5) {
   // divides each line by commas
      Scanner lineInput = new Scanner(firstLineOfFile).useDelimiter(",");
   //get the two headers from the first line of the file   
      String header1 = lineInput.next();
      String header2 = lineInput.next();
      String header3 = lineInput.next();

   // display headings
      System.out.println("Row        " + header1 + "    " + header2 + "    " + header3);
      // loop through the array
      for (int i = 0; i < listSize; i++) {
          // display grocery list items as a numbered list
         System.out.printf("%2d     %8s     %3d\n", i+1, itemNames5[i], itemNumbers5[i], StoreNames5[i]);
      }
   }

   /**
    * Write grocery list array to file
    * 
    * @param names is the grocery list names
    * @param numbers is the grocery list numbers
    * @param listSize is the size of the grocery list
    */
   public static void writeToFile(String outputFile, String[] names,
       Integer[] numbers, Integer listSize, String [] store) {
      // "PrintWriter" is a Class Used To Write to A File.
      PrintWriter fileWriter = null;
      try {
         /*
          * Must use try-catch block, because PrintWriter may throw
          * FileNotFoundException, which is a checked exception. This will connect
          * to a file in the current directory. If the file does not exists, a new
          * file will be created. If the file does exists, the file will be
          * overwritten.
          */
         fileWriter = new PrintWriter(outputFile);
      } 
      catch (FileNotFoundException exception) {
         // Print error message.
         // In order to print double quotes("),
         // the escape sequence for double quotes (\") must be used.
         System.out.print("ERROR: File not found for \"");
         System.out.println(outputFile + "\"");
      }
      // if file opened successfully, then below code executes..
      // continue program if writeToFile is not "null"
      if (fileWriter != null) {
      //write the headings to the first line of the file
         fileWriter.println(firstLineOfFile);

         // loop through list (grocery list) and write to file
         for (int i = 0; i < listSize; i++) {
            fileWriter.println(names[i]+","+numbers[i]+","+store[i]);
         }
         // REMEMBER: always give feedback to the user!
         System.out.println("Wrote to file: " + outputFile);
         // WARNING: don't forget to close the file!
         // will not write to file if not closed!
         fileWriter.close();
      }// end of "if" statement for writeToFile

   }

}// end of class
```

My I/O

```
Read from file: input4.csv

    GROCERY LIST MENU
     Enter 1 to Add
     Enter 2 to Delete
     Enter 3 to Display
     Enter 4 to Quit
    Enter your choice: 3

Row        Name    Number    Store
 1        natto       3
 2         eggs      12
 3     shiitake       1
 4         negi       1
 5       garlic       5
 6     umeboshi       1
```

Store is not showing when I press 3 to display arrays. Nothing is showing

I can use the #1 option to add the name, and number of items and store but I can't see it when I redisplay it  but it's not showing the store but only the `itemname` and `itemnumber`

Same goes for option #2 which is deleting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you aren't able to display is because inside of the display method you forget to add another format string inside System.out.println() so you needed to add another %s to account for your StoreNames[i].

```
public static void display(String[] itemNames5, 
    Integer[] itemNumbers5, Integer listSize, String [] StoreNames5) {
    // divides each line by commas
    Scanner lineInput = new Scanner(firstLineOfFile).useDelimiter(",");
    //get the two headers from the first line of the file   
    String header1 = lineInput.next();
    String header2 = lineInput.next();
    String header3 = lineInput.next();

    // display headings
    System.out.println("Row        " + header1 + "    " + header2 + "    " +      header3);
    // loop through the array
    for (int i = 0; i < listSize; i++) {
      // display grocery list items as a numbered list
      System.out.printf("%2d     %8s     %3d    %8s\n", i+1, itemNames5[i],  itemNumbers5[i], StoreNames5[i]);
  }
```

}